# How to replace Nautilus with Nemo in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, 14.04, nemo

I would like to replace Nautilus(Default gnome shell file manager) with [Nemo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo_%28file_manager%29) file manger in Gnome 3.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/02/set-nemo-as-default-file-manager-in.html),

After Nemo file manager installation, set Nemo as default File-Manager and allow desktop handling by Nemo open Terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

Now enter this command in terminal to check that now Nemo is your default file manager :

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

---

If you want to go back with Nautilus as default File Manager try these commands:

```
xdg-mime default nautilus*.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

Comment: After changing, the places function in the top bar didn't work anymore. Removing and re-enabling it made it work with Nemo.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily install nemo without cinnamon dependencies, as shown [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html):

> ***Warning:*** do not use this PPA if you're using Linux Mint or if you use
>   Cinnamon in Ubuntu! Also, if you've added any Cinnamon PPAs, remove
>   them before using the WebUpd8 Nemo PPA even if you didn't install
>   Cinnamon, or else the Nemo version in the WebUpd8 Nemo PPA might be
>   overwritten.
>
> 1. Install Nemo:
>     
>      *Update: the PPA now provides Nemo 2.6 for Ubuntu 14.04, 14.10 and
>      15.04!*
>     
>      Add the PPA and install the latest Nemo with Unity tweaks/fixes by
>      using the commands below:
>
>    ```
>    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
>    sudo apt-get update
>    sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
>    ```

Comment: Works in 16.04 on ubuntu GNOME as well