# Having replaced Nautilus with nemo, browser upload remains using nautilus

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, nemo

As the title says.

I've followed all steps in google results, checked a few answers here, like this one:

[How to replace Nautilus with Nemo in Gnome 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481742/how-to-replace-nautilus-with-nemo-in-gnome-3)

Or this one:

[Make nemo the default file browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260244/make-nemo-the-default-file-browser)

But in both cases, the when I choose to upload a file in a browser, it still defaults back to the view nautilus provides.

What am I missing here? What's the last piece? I really don't like the limited abilities of the upload interface that Nautilus provides.

Comment: The file chosser is not nautilus, it's gnome or gtk.. whatever, but not nautilus.

Comment: I agree with @doug. It's [gtk file chooser](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html). I think there is no easy way (if any) how to change this without hard intervention into the system. Related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656333/file-chooser-view-settings).

Comment: And the second link in your question is about which browser will open, when you click on downloaded file folder.

Comment: @BlueManCZ Ok then. I had hoped it would be configurable easily.